# Regarding retagging of a particular question

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

Not really sure about this. I stumbled upon this question:

[Is there a way to check how long you've been playing a DRM-free game with no in-game counter?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199023/is-there-a-way-to-check-how-long-youve-been-playing-a-drm-free-game-with-no-in)

It was tagged with a [planescape-torment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planescape-torment) tag, but, obviously, the matter is not exclusive to that game. I replaced it with [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues), since that seems to come closest to the nature of the problem.
Is this a proper retagging, or is there a more suitable tag for questions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no appropriate tag because that question is off-topic, since it's not strictly about video games. It's asking for a way to track time spent on a certain program in Windows.

Comment: This Meta is about *tagging* of a question, not its close reason. Also at the time of this Meta post the question was still open.

Comment: @dly the point Wrigglenite is bringing out is that off topic questions might not have tags that are appropriate for the question, because it is off topic. You don't need worry about trying to come up with the most correct tag for every off topic question, just vtc/vtd it.

Comment: @Dragonrage alright. IMHO the answer was just completely out of scope before the edit by just saying the question is off-topic, because at the time of the Meta it wasn't yet closed. If xFire would still exist it could even be answered with a gaming related software.

Comment: Questions don't have to be closed to be off-topic. We specialized in matters related to video games, so of course you'd have trouble tagging a question unrelated to games. I thought that was obvious, but I clarified nonetheless.